# Diagonal Test on 8 Queens

Tags: c++, diagonal, n-queens

I am fully aware that this code is not efficient... I'm new to C++ and this is my first shot at a solutions program...

The issue is that when I run the program it returns no results. I've tried debugging and it seems my problem is in the diagonals test...

I realized that when I set slope==1 or slope==-1 then it gives 480 results but when i set slope==1 || slope==-1 it gives no results. I feel like I'm missing something logically. So I think the problem is in the last part of my function clash.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void print (bool a[8][8]){
for (int r=0; r<8; r++){
    for (int c=0; c<8; c++){
        if (a[r][c]==true) cout<<"X";
        else cout<<"E";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}


void XYdivide (bool a[][8], int xplace[], int yplace[]){
int uptonumber=0;
for (int r=0; r<8; r++){
    for (int c=0; c<8; c++){
        if (a[c][r]) { yplace[uptonumber]=c; xplace[uptonumber]=r; uptonumber++;}
    }
}
}



bool clash (bool a[8][8]){
static int total=1;
int Columncounter;
for (int r=0; r<8; r++){ //tests columns
    Columncounter=0;
    for (int c=0; c<8; c++){
        if (a[r][c]) Columncounter++;
        if (Columncounter>1) return false;
    }
}
int Rowcounter;
for (int c=0; c<8; c++){ //tests rows
    Rowcounter=0;
    for (int r=0; r<8; r++){
        if (a[r][c]) Rowcounter++;
        if (Rowcounter>1) return false;
    }
}
int xvalues [8]; int yvalues[8];
XYdivide(a , xvalues, yvalues);
for (int i=0; i<8; i++){ //test diagonals
    for (int j=0; j<8; j++){
        int slope=(yvalues[i]-yvalues[j]) / (0.0+xvalues[i]-xvalues[j]);
        if (slope==-1 || slope==1) return false;
    }
}
print (a); cout<<endl<<total++<< endl; return true;
}


int main (){
bool a[8][8]={false};

cout<<"starting"<<endl;

for (int r0=0; r0<8; r0++){
    a[0][r0]=true;
    if (r0>0) a[0][r0-1]=false;


    for (int r1=0; r1<8; r1++){
        a[1][r1]=true;
        if (r1>0) a[1][r1-1]=false;
        if (r1==0) a[1][7]=false;


        for (int r2=0; r2<8; r2++){
            a[2][r2]=true;
            if (r2>0) a[2][r2-1]=false;
            if (r2==0) a[2][7]=false;


            for (int r3=0; r3<8; r3++){
                a[3][r3]=true;
                if (r3>0) a[3][r3-1]=false;
                if (r3==0) a[3][7]=false;


                for (int r4=0; r4<8; r4++){
                    if (r4>0) a[4][r4-1]=false;
                    if (r4==0) a[4][7]=false;
                    a[4][r4]=true;


                    for (int r5=0; r5<8; r5++){
                        a[5][r5]=true;
                        if (r5>0) a[5][r5-1]=false;
                        if (r5==0) a[5][7]=false;


                        for (int r6=0; r6<8; r6++){
                            a[6][r6]=true;
                            if (r6>0) a[6][r6-1]=false;
                            if (r6==0) a[6][7]=false;


                            for (int r7=0; r7<8; r7++){
                                a[7][r7]=true;
                                if (r7>0) a[7][r7-1]=false;
                                if (r7==0) a[7][7]=false;
                                clash(a);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;


}
```

Comment: I really don't think you want that 8-level loop. :s

Comment: It seems to work perfectly. Yes as I wrote: Its my first attempt and quite inefficient!

Comment: More efficiently would be to check for the clash each time you add another piece on the board, assuming that before that there was no clash. In that case you only have to check the lines that intersect on the new piece, instead of checking the whole board.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was I was using int slope. So it was truncating the end of the slope answer. and would put 1.3 or whatever as 1. Switch it to double!

---

```
for (int j=0; j<8; j++){
    double slope=(yvalues[i]-yvalues[j]) / (0.0+xvalues[i]-xvalues[j]);
    if (slope==-1 || slope==1) return false;
}
```

Comment: No No No - you can't compare a calculated floating point value for equality.

Comment: can you explain further? What does that mean?